# Connecting multiple dom elements using jsPlumb

Tags: jquery, jsplumb

I'm using jsPlumb to connect div elements on a page, using the following code

```
var sourceDiv = $("#a");
var targetDiv1 = $("#b");
var targetDiv2 = $("#b");

jsPlumb.connect({
    source: sourceDiv, 
    target: targetDiv1,
    anchors: ["BottomLeft", "TopCenter"],
    paintStyle: { strokeStyle: "blue", lineWidth: 5 },
    connector: ["Flowchart", { minStubLength: 40}]
});

jsPlumb.connect({
    source: sourceDiv, 
    target: targetDiv2,
    anchors: ["BottomRight", "TopCenter"],
    paintStyle: { strokeStyle: "blue", lineWidth: 5 },
    connector: ["Flowchart", { minStubLength: 40}]
});
```

This works fine, but I have lots of elements to connect on a page.

How can I change the above code so that instead of doing each set of connections individually I have some kind of array containing all of my connections (source and target) settings then have a loop to parse the connections (source and target) in a loop like a for each?

Something like this for the data structure:

```
var connections = new Array();
connection[0] = $('#a'), $('#b');
connection[1] = $('#a'), $('#b');
connection[2] = $('#b'), $('#c');
connection[3] = $('#c'), $('#d');
```

Where the first dom element is the source, then the second is the target. Probably need to extend this to specify the position as well.

Any ideas gratefully received.

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
var connections = new Array();
connections[0] = {src: "#a", tgt:"#b"};
connections[1] = {src: "#a", tgt:"#b"};
connections[2] = {src: "#b", tgt:"#c"};
connections[3] = {src: "#c", tgt:"#d"};
for(var index = 0; index < connections.length; index++) {
    var con = jsPlumb.connect({
        source: $($("html").find(connections[index].src)),
        target: $($("html").find(connections[index].tgt))
    });           
}
```